Getting "Operation not permitted" on Volumes location when trying to run the job in Unity Catalog enabled cluster
I am trying to run a job in Unity catalog enabled cluster. File is copied into the volume location and trying to perform decryption.
In the compute tab of job run I can see compute node as Single user and in the summary "Unity Catalog"
I am able to access the volume location through the interactive cluster notebook but not when triggered through the job.
gpg: can't open '/Volumes/<catalog_name>/<schema>/<volume name>/source/region_data_20241121.asc': Operation not permitted
gpg: decrypt_message failed: Operation not permitted
gzip: /Volumes/<catalog_name>/<schema>/<volume name>/source/region_data_20241121.dat.gz: Operation not permitted

I am able to import the keys. But getting "operation not permitted" when trying to decrypt the file.

val importPublicKeyCommand = s"gpg --batch --yes --import /dbfs/$privateKeyFilePath$privatekeyFile".!!

val decryptFile = if (ucEnabled) s"""gpg --batch --yes --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase $passPhrase --output  /$mountPath/$fileName --decrypt /$mountPath/$gpgFileName""" else s"""gpg --batch --yes --pinentry-mode loopback --passphrase $passPhrase --output  /dbfs/$mountPath/$fileName --decrypt /dbfs/$mountPath/$gpgFileName"""

decryptFile.!


Sounds like a permission issue with the file.

@Sachin Shetty By any chance are you using Azure databricks?
